# Custom labels with enumitem

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Is there a way to use `\setlist` in the `enumitem` package to get a structure like

> FF 1: This is research question 1. 
>  
>   H_1.1: This is statistical hypothesis 1.1.
>  
>   H_1.2: This is statistical hypothesis 1.2.
>   FF 1: This is research question 2.
>   H_2.1: This is statistical hypothesis 2.1.
>   H_2.2: This is statistical hypothesis 2.2.

So technically I have to change the prefix for the labels for different levels of the list. All I have achieved until now is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{forschungsfragen}{enumerate}{2}    

\setlist[forschungsfragen,1]{label=FF \arabic*:, ref=\arabic*} 
\setlist[forschungsfragen,2]{label=$H_{\arabic*}$:, ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{forschungsfragen}
     \item This is research question 1
        \begin{forschungsfragen}
            \item This is statistical hypothesis 1.1.
            \item This is statistical hypothesis 1.2.
        \end{forschungsfragen}  
     \item This is research question 2
        \begin{forschungsfragen}
            \item This is statistical hypothesis 2.1.
            \item This is statistical hypothesis 2.2.
        \end{forschungsfragen}  
\end{forschungsfragen}

\end{document}
```

So how can I get the counter of the research question level shown on *while* having "H_" as a prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the value `ref=` option, one has to make some choices, but basically, all comes down to the fact that the counter value of the first level must be included here.

Since `\newlist{forschungsfragen}{enumerate}{2}` is applied, corresponding counters named `forschungsfrageni` and `forschungsfragenii` are defined, the first one responsible for the first level, as such `\theforschungsfrageni` is the relevant counter formatter command. (From a native German speaker point of view: `forschungsfrageni` does look weird :D)

The `i` and `ii` indicate the level number in `roman` figures

If the `ref` - format for the first level is changed, I suggest to use `\arabic{forschungsfrageni}` however rather than `\theforschungsfrageni`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{forschungsfragen}{enumerate}{2}    

\setlist[forschungsfragen,1]{label={FF \arabic*:}, ref={\arabic*}} 
\setlist[forschungsfragen,2]{label={$H_{\theforschungsfrageni.\arabic*}$:}, ref={H\arabic{forschungsfrageni}.\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forschungsfragen}
\item This is research question 1 \label{frage}
  \begin{forschungsfragen}
  \item This is statistical hypothesis 1.1. 
  \item This is statistical hypothesis 1.2.
  \end{forschungsfragen}  
\item This is research question 2
  \begin{forschungsfragen}
  \item This is statistical hypothesis 2.1. \label{foo}
  \item This is statistical hypothesis 2.2. \label{foobar}
  \end{forschungsfragen}  
\end{forschungsfragen}

In \ref{foobar} gab es eine extrem wichtige Hypothese, während \ref{frage} noch nicht abschliessend geklärt ist!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest the usage of `cleveref` in order to make the reference formating nicer